# How do you work with the Epson V600 film/print scanner using Xsane?

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

Trying to get a Epson V600 Film/Print scanner to work with any version of Ubuntu or Linux. Using Xsane, the software does not recognize the V600 scanner. But it does recognize my combo printer scanners. I have tried to get Xsane to recognize this scanner with two completely different Linux operating systems. It hasn't worked so far.

(Note: This is a 120mm or smaller film/slide/print scanner capable of 12,800 dpi with scan error correction built into the hardware. (ICE))

I am presuming that I need some sort of support file, but I don't know what it is.

I have read where Ubuntu supported previous and lighter versions of this scanner. But I have not had this luck with the V600.

Anyone know what I need to make this scanner work with a Linux system?

Comment: Epson provide a scanner driver for the V600  it comes down as iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz from here http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-x820&version=1.0.1 and if you save it to your Downloads folder; (the default setup) then the commands to install it would be `cd Downloads` and `tar -zxvf iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz` and then `sudo dpkg -i iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb` and the final command installs the decompressed package; if you copy each command; and paste it into the terminal; to paste, right-click at the text prompt and select from menu

Comment: I had that already installed, but I did re-install it. No help.

Comment: on SANE, the open-source font for linux; it says the V600 has good support http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-EPSON; one can join their mailing list to ask for assistance http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel and you could install the latest version of sane by using the Rolf Bensch ppa  https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git and beyond that one tries the things in the Ubuntu wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo eg `sane-find-scanner` and `scanimage -L` and then those commands with sudo in front of them; please post them back

Comment: I will try that. I did go to the Xsane.org website, where it says that the last support on this project was in 2010. And while Xsane version 0.999 is used on Ubuntu, the website states that there was a version 1.0, and 1.1. And also 2.0 was nearly ready for release in 2010. Related: I have Knoppix on a memory stick. I did get it to recognize my V600. But the scanner started sounding an alarm. I stopped trying Knoppix at this point.

Comment: sane-project.org shows: "Perfection V600 Photo USB 0x04b8/0x013a Unsupported supported by the epkowa backend plus non-free interpreter" The part that caught my attention was "Unsupported"

Answer (score 1):

there's a current bug in 18.04 && 18.10

- i installed the latest version of libsane from Rold Bensch's ppa as @pdc mentioned above (dunno if necessary)
- i ran install.sh from the epson linux .deb (particular bundle for my v550)
- bug tracker gave me info to give a symbolic link to the proprietary epson libraries (called epkowa)

run:

`sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012